# Rewrite module to handle site version folders (strip slash)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, version, slash

I'm using the following rule to use folders for different versions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=VERSION:020]
RewriteRule ^versions/(.*)$ versions/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ versions/%{ENV:VERSION}/$1 [L]
```

I have a structure like:

```
http://domain.com/versions/020/
http://domain.com/versions/020/th?=1
http://domain.com/versions/020/myfolder/
http://domain.com/versions/020/myfile.html
```

But the user can see:

```
http://domain.com/
http://domain.com/th?=1
http://domain.com/myfolder/
http://domain.com/myfile.html
```

I have a last problem with a slash that shows the version number.

A second entry point is (still working):

http://domain.com/site/

But the problem when the user type the url and omit the end forward slash, like this:

http://domain.com/site

The user now see the version number like this:

http://domain.com/versions/020/site/

This is a problem as I don't want the user to find out about other versions.

Any idea how I can solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is interfering with mod_dir, which by default redirects the browser when it tried to access a directory and the trailing slash is missing. What's happening is the Rewrite is occuring, changing `/site` to `/versions/020/site` then mod_dir is redirecting the browser to `http://domain.com/versions/020/site/`. Thus the browser sees the versions/020 stuff in the location bar.

You can turn off mod_dir's automatic redirect with the ["DirectorySlash Off" directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash). But you may want to add the trailing slash anyways by including a redirect before any rewrites happen.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ $1/ [R,L]
```

This or something equivalent before you do the rewrite to `/version/020` should hopefully fix it.

Edit: Actually, now that I'm thinking about it, if you rewrite/redirect when trailing slash is missing, you don't need to turn off `DirectorySlash` because it'll always have a trailing slash by the time it gets to mod_dir. Maybe do it anyways to be safe?